# Chrome scrollbar takes up space but is invisible till styled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, scrollbar

I have a PWA where I turn off scrollbars. for Chrome I've used: -

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Now for non-touch PC users I want to turn scrollbars on for certain elements. The problem is when I get rid of "Display: None" I get the space for a scrollbar but it's invisible. When I style it (eg: background-color) I can see it.

Why is it invisible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spewin' When you define the pseudo element you have to take control of *ALL* attributes :-(

Remove the CSS pseudo-element definition completely an the scrollbars go back to defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Just make document scrollbar invisible, pseudo selector can be tied to an element.

```
html::-webkit-scrollbar,
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```